# How to fully use .proto files in a Visual Studio C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

The following file is called `network_connection.proto`.

```
import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

extend .google.protobuf.EnumValueOptions {
    optional string network_connection_token = 50500;
}

enum ENetworkDisconnectionReason {
    NETWORK_DISCONNECT_INVALID = 0;
    NETWORK_DISCONNECT_SHUTDOWN = 1;
    NETWORK_DISCONNECT_DISCONNECT_BY_USER = 2 [(network_connection_token) = "#GameUI_Disconnect_User"];
}
```

In my C++ project, in a source file, I'm about to use `::ENetworkDisconnectionReason g_eReason{ };`. Visual Studio is saying that `ENetworkDisconnectionReason` is an unknown type. How to properly include `network_connection.proto` into my project so I can use its data into C++ source and header files? I note that I've already dragged & dropped `network_connection.proto` into my project.

Visual Studio is saying that `ENetworkDisconnectionReason` is an unknown type.
I've dragged & dropped `network_connection.proto` file into the project but nothing happened.
I've tried to add `#include <network_connection.proto>` into my source file, didn't help.

Comment: Just adding the proto file is not going to help. Either use a package manager to install protobuf (and gRPC) packages (or clone them from git). Then make use all your include paths are set (a package manager will do this). And you will have to add a manual compilation step to your proto file. There should be plenty of manuals around online to help you do this.

Comment: You are right. I've used `protoc` to manually convert `.proto` file to `.pb.h` & `.pb.cc` files.